# I keep getting #NA

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

`=IF(and(or(U3="Pro",U3="Standard"),T3>0,"Charged",If(and(U3="Lite",T2.+0),"Charged","FOC")))`

Got a #NA Error
Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments.

Comment: I think you have to check your `AND` and `OR` brackets - like this they don't make sense.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75056389/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) that shows say ten rows of sample data side-by-side with your manually entered desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstand what you're trying to achieve, you're missing a parenthesis after T3>0 in order to close the AND clauses:

```
=IF(and(or(U3="Pro",U3="Standard"),T3>0),"Charged",If(and(U3="Lite",T2.+0),"Charged","FOC"))
```

And I don't know what you meant with "T2.+0"

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(AND(OR(U3="Pro", U3="Standard"), T3>0), "Charged", 
 IF(AND(U3="Lite", T2+0), "Charged", "FOC"))
```

or:

```
=IF((REGEXMATCH(U3, "Pro|Standard"))*(T3>0), "Charged", 
 IF((U3="Lite")*(T2+0), "Charged", "FOC"))
```

Comment: =IF((REGEXMATCH(U3, "Pro|Standard")*(T3>0), "Charged", 
 IF((U3="Lite")*(T2+0), "Charged", "FOC"))   Results: Error
Formula parse error.

Comment: =IF(AND(OR(U3="Pro", U3="Standard"), T3>0), "Charged", 
 IF(AND(U3="Lite", T2+0), "Charged", "FOC"))  Result: Error
Function ADD parameter 1 expects number values. But 'Ignore' is a text and cannot be coerced to a number.

Comment: @AngelinaRanai fixed. try the 2nd formula now

Answer (score 0):

Try `ifs()`, like this:

```
=ifs( 
  T3 = "", iferror(1/0), 
  T3 < 0, "Reimbursement", 
  T3 = 0, "Free of charge", 
  true, "Charged" 
)
```